# How to load properties file only once?

Tags: java

I am reading the email message by getting the data from properties file.I am using timer schedule to read the new message after some time at regular interval.How can i do this?

TimerSchedule.java

```
public class TimeScheduler
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        GmailConfiguration gmailConfiguration = new GmailConfiguration();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                gmailConfiguration.configure();
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 500, 30000);
    }
}
```

I am getting data from properties file in GmailConfiguration.java

Here is my GmailConfiguration.java

```
public class GmailConfiguration
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GmailConfiguration.class);

    public void configure()
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try
        {
            String propertyFileName = "emailServer.properties";
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName);

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            JSONArray jadata = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Servers");
            int len = jadata.size();
            AccessMailMessages readGmail = new AccessMailMessages();
            JSONObject server;
            String name;
            String host;
            String username;
            String password;
            int port;
            String folderName;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                server = (JSONObject) jadata.get(i);
                name = (String) server.get("Name");
                host = (String) server.get("Host");
                username = (String) server.get("UserName");
                password = (String) server.get("Password");
                port = ((Long) server.get("Port")).intValue();
                folderName = (String) server.get("FolderName");

                readGmail.recieveGmail(name, host, port, username, password, folderName);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. You want to do something "only once" but then talk about a timer task which executes on a schedule.

Comment: Sorry man, But i want to ask when program is execute for first time then only it load the data from properties file after that it reuse the same loaded data. The program is in in such way that it executes again and again after some fixed interval time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the `Configuration` class from the `EmailReceiver` class:

```java
// Utilizes "Singleton" pattern
class GmailConfiguration {
  private static final GmailConfiguration INSTANCE = new GmailConfiguration();

  boolean isConfigured;
  String host;
  String port;
  //etc.

  public void configure() {
    if (!isConfigured) {
      // read in the properties, populate host/port etc.
      isConfigured = true;
    }
    // when called for the second time, reading won't happen
  }
}
```

then, as for receiving the email:

```java
class GmailReceiver {
  public void receive() {
    AccessMailMessages readGmail = new AccessMailMessages();
    GmailConfiguration config = GmailConfiguration.INSTANCE;
    config.configure();
    readGmail.recieveGmail(config.getName(),
        config.getHost(), 
        config.getPort() /* etc */);

  }
}
```

and make sure to only schedule `GmailReceiver`